# Remove post meta keys

Tags: post-meta

I've got a lot of post meta keys that I no longer use, and I'm trying to work out how to delete them so they no longer show in the custom fields list in the admin panel.

[image]

This code will delete the post meta values:

```
function hp_batch_delete_post_meta(){

    // get array of all post ids
    $post_ids = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'fields'        => 'ids',
        'post_type'     => array('ad_upload','post', 'page'),
        'post_status'   => array('publish', 'auto-draft', 'trash', 'pending', 'draft'),
    ) );

    // remove post meta for each post
    foreach( $post_ids as $post_id ) { 
        delete_post_meta($post_id, 'my_postmeta_key_1');
        delete_post_meta($post_id, 'my_postmeta_key_2');
        delete_post_meta($post_id, 'my_postmeta_key_3');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'hp_batch_delete_post_meta');
```

But I would like to completely remove the meta keys too so they don't show in that admin list.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Those meta keys might still exist in the database. You could try to run the following query and see if there are any orphaned meta keys `SELECT *  FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} as pm  LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} as p ON pm.post_id = p.ID WHERE p.ID IS NULL`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this from just a Google search ([Source](https://www.iftekhar.net/how-to-delete-unnecessary-post-metadata-from-wordpress/))

You have to change met value keys as you want. However, it is highly recommend to take a **DB backup** before running this code.

```
<?php
function delete_useless_post_meta() {
   global $wpdb;
   $table = $wpdb->prefix.'postmeta';
   $wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_edit_last'));
   $wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_edit_lock'));
   $wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_wp_old_slug')); }
add_action('wp_logout','delete_useless_post_meta');
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

This is quite an old post, but there is a much better way to do this.

WordPress core has a function where you can delete all meta data by a key.

```
delete_metadata( string $meta_type, int $object_id, string $meta_key, mixed $meta_value = '', bool $delete_all = false );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_metadata/

Use it this way:

```
delete_metadata( 'post', 0, 'meta_key_to_delete', false, true );
```

This would apply to all post types, published status, etc. So to delete the examples meta keys as above:

```
$deletable = array( 'my_postmeta_key_1', 'my_postmeta_key_2', 'my_postmeta_key_3' );
foreach( $deleteable as $to_delete ) {
  delete_metadata( 'post', 0, $to_delete, false, true );
}
```

Comment: I can't believe this answer isn't getting more upvotes!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to delete keys with a wildcard criteria of some sort (as I did) then you can do this directly in SQL.

```
DELETE FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'weather_%'
```